# I do I parse the string from req.query?

Tags: node.js, express

I am supposed to retrieve the string from my req.query in express. I am implementing a RESTFul API and my code looks like

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    var count = req.query.count;
    var sorting = req.query.sort;
    //let obj = JSON.parse(sorting)


    if(count == "true") {
        user.find({}, function(err, users) {
            if(err){
                res.status(404).send({
                    message: err,
                    data: []
                });
            } else {
                res.status(200).send({
                    message: 'OK ttt',
                    data: users.length
                });
            }
    });
    }
```

Let's say my

```
var sorting = req.query.sort
```

Give me {\"name\": 1}"

I want to parse out the "name" from this.

I used

```
JSON.parse(sorting)
```

But it returned an object, not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.parse` indeed returns an object: The object parsed from the JSON string you pass to the function. In this case it will return the object `{name: 1}`.

To get the value for the name property you can do:

```
var name = JSON.parse(sorting).name;
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. Not sure if you're able to answer on follow-up question, in {\"name\": 1}", what is that \ ? Why cant it just be { "name" : 1 }?

Comment: The backslash is an escape character, which makes sure that `"` gets interpretted as a character within the string. Consider `var json = "{"name": 1}"`. Notice the multiple uses of `"`. This would result in a syntax error. Therefor escape characters are used.

Comment: Thanks again. BTW I understand that JSON.parse(sorting).name returns 1, which is the value for 'name'. How can I return the key ("name")?

Comment: You want to check if the parsed object contains a property called `"name"`. To check this you can do: `var objectContainsName = JSON.parse(sorting).hasOwnProperty("name");`

Comment: No I meant, I just want to parse the string "name"

Comment: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(JSON.parse(sorting))[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You can access the value of the name property by storing the parsed data in a variable and then accessing its property:

```
var parsedSorting = JSON.parse(sorting)
console.log(parsedSorting.name) // will log the value of name
```